# Word Addins not available when opening document from intranet

Tags: ms-word, add-in

I have a docm file with a ribbon and some buttons on it. Whenever I open the file via Webbrower, my ribbon is not available. When I save the file and open it again, the ribbon appears again.

I tried to add my intranet site as a trusted site in the internet settings, and i disabled the "protected view" in word. Im using office 2010.

Anyone having an idea, why word doesn't show my ribbon?

Comment: Probably due to Word's Trust Center settings. File/OPtions/Trust Center.

Comment: I checked already my trust center settings, but i didn't find anything that helped.